# Пытался сохранить в localStorage , но перестала создаваться разметка

Tags: javascript

**При запуске нет ни одной заметки, js сам создаёт с первой заметки**
**Сам код:**

```
const containerNote = document.querySelector('.note-container')


let itemsArray = (!localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [])

itemsArray.forEach(item => {
    let displayNote = `
        <div class="card w-100 mt-5">
            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="note-date">
                    ${time()}
                </div>

                <div class="checkers">
                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" class="input-focus mr-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" onclick="delNote(this)">Delete button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="w-100" style="border: 0"
                onfocus="addFocusToNote(this)" onblur="removeFocusToNote(this)"
                ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
    containerNote.innerHTML += displayNote
})

let createNote = () => {
    document.querySelector('.btn-addNote').addEventListener('click', () => {
        itemsArray = [...itemsArray, 1]
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
    })
}

createNote()

let delNote = (that) => {
    that.closest('div.card').remove()
}

let addFocusToNote = (that) => {
    that.closest('div.card').querySelector('.input-focus').checked = true
}

let removeFocusToNote = (that) => {
    that.closest('div.card').querySelector('.input-focus').checked = false
}

let time = () => {
    let today = new Date()
    let day = today.getDay()
    let month = today.getMonth()
    let year = today.getFullYear()
    return `${day}.${month}.${year}`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в предыдущем вопросе/ответе перепутали условие:

```
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items')? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];
```

Вы, конечно, пользуйтесь кодом, который Вам здесь дают, но проверяйте, что он делает.

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'time' before initialization
поставил функцию time перед циклом forEach , теперь заметки появляются в localSrorage , и после обновление страницы заметки появляются , но новые не добавляются

Comment: @EdmondKirsh Задайте про это другой вопрос.